# MongoDB Aggregation - Query array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with this data:

```
[
    {
        _id: "123",
        number: 10,
        users: [
            {
                amount: 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "456",
        number: 20,
        users: [
            {
                amount: 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to find documents where `users[0].amount` is greater than or equal to `number`. I have the following Mongoose query:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $gte: ["$users.0.amount", "$number"] },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

However, this doesn't seem to be filtering the documents properly. I'm assuming `$users.0.amount` isn't the correct syntax. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) requires Aggregation Framework's syntax so you have to use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) instead:

```
{  $gte: [ { $arrayElemAt: [  "$users.amount",  0] }, "$number" ] }
```

where `users.amount` is an array of numbers

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U1aqembWD1P)

Comment: Thanks, this works, I'll accept the answer after the timer is up